# PHP: Is there a better way than looping through "while ($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))"?

Tags: php, sqlite, while-loop

I have a table as below in SQLite3 (the list could be much longer.):

```
id  cid         uname           date
1   33788127    6155ce36e45b4   20210930 104822
2   56198567    6155ce387f0cd   20210930 104824
3   27255356    6155ce399e1ca   20210930 104825
4   59519951    6155ce3a7ae0d   20210930 104826
```

I'd like to get all `cid`s from the table.

Currently, I'm using the below function to get the `cid` list:

```
    function getCidList () {
        $db = new SQLite3($this->db_file);
        $table = $this->table;
        $sql2 ="SELECT cid FROM $table";
        $results = $db->query($sql2);
        $res = [];
        while ($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
                array_push($res, $row['cid']);
        }
        $db->close();
        return $res;
    }
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 33788127
    [1] => 56198567
    [2] => 27255356
    [3] => 59519951
)
```

My question is: Is this the best way to get the intended result? (I feel like `looping` might not be the most efficient way when the list becomes longer, but I have not been able to find alternative ways). Is there an easier way to get the `cid` list other than using the `while` loop?

```
        while ($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
                array_push($res, $row['cid']);
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am not very familiar with SQLite, but if you use PDO, and if your data set is small, you can use `fetchAll` which will fetch all rows into memory. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php. If your data set is larger, then fetching each row in a loop is standard practice.

Comment: Nope, that's pretty much it. You shouldn't use `array_push` to add one item to an array, though. `$res[] = $row['cid']` would be preferable.

Comment: Thanks, @waterloomatt. I never tried PDO. Just tried and got what i wanted.

Comment: Thanks, @Don'tPanic. Your suggestion is also helpful.